# What is data per- processing in sim function Neural Network

Tags: matlab, neural-network

When I try to simulated the sim function job
I did the fallowing function code

```
function [ out ] = Mysim (net,input )

y1 = tansig( net.IW{1,1}*p1+ net.b{1};);
 out =tansig(net.LW{2,1}*y1 + net.b{2};);
end
```

My qeustion is about data per- processing in sim function.. ?

((( My data input is NOT 0, 1 )))

By the way I used in trained network the default setting of per- processing and when I type.. :

```
net.inputs{1}.processFcns : 'fixunknowns' 'removeconstantrows' 'mapminmax'

net.outputs{2}.processFcns: 'removeconstantrows' 'mapminmax'
```

How can I joind these in mysim function to have results as matlab sim function ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I have understood correctly...however, the strings inside `processFcns` are the names of the functions applied in pre-processing (before sim) and post-processing (after sim), so you can check the docs for these functions, using the parameters stored also in the `inputs` and `outputs` structures...

Comment: I did what you say .. My problem is the results of this code
 
 [pn,ps] = mapminmax(p);
 [tn,ts] = mapminmax(t);
 net = train(net,pn,tn);
 an = sim(net,pn);
 a = mapminmax('reverse',an,ts);
which is differnet when I replces matlab sim with mysim  I post it in my question !! Any ieads plz ?

Comment: Are you sure to have a NN with tansig both in hidden and output layer?

Comment: Yes I'm sure ! I have used that net = newff(P,T1,HN,{'tansig' 'tansig'},'trainscg');

Comment: try removing normalization, i.e. emptying processFcns and try again, in this way we'll understand where the problem is...

Comment: Thanks.. I found the solution You must apply all per- processing function NOT only the normalization so then you got the same results of MATLAB sim function ... here the answer .. http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-6HR2S2/index.html?product=NN&solution=1-6HR2S2  ..... Thanxxxxxx